# Make sure the bottom bar is displayed when linking to Google Maps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and linking from a web page to Google Maps (as an external link).  I would like the bottom bar to be visible in the map so that the user can hit the back button.

This works if the link looks like this:

```
<a  rel="external" target="_" href="http://maps.google.co.uk">Text</a>
```

However if its like this

```
<a  rel="external" target="_" href="http://maps.google.co.uk?ll=55,-4">Text</a>
```

then the Google Map page is fullscreen and there is no back button.

So how can I use parameters with the map and NOT have full-screen, but retain the bottom bar.

I DONT want to use the JavaScript API as I want to provide instructions for public transport which are not available from JavaScript (yet).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Mobile Safari has a special URL scheme for maps, so that the reference with parameters is being redirected to the iOS maps application, rather than the maps web site.  There is some developer documentation relating to this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1).

This seems wrong as you're thrown out of mobile safari and don't have the option of going to the mobile site.  It may be a bug, as the behaviour only occurs when there are parameters.  I would like to know why this is the case.